# Are there non-root chalices I can get blood rocks from?

Tags: bloodborne

Each type of chalice (Pthumeru, Loran, and Isz) can yield one Blood Rock among the treasures found in chests. There are well known glyph to get these, but a majority are root chalices with some nasty additional rites that I don't quite want to spend the time on now.

**Are there standard chalices that I can use to get my three blood rocks with easy accessibility?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are glyphs for standard *Pthumeru Ihyll*, *Lower Loran*, and *Great Isz* which grant you Blood Rocks, all on the *first layer pre-dungeons***.

Their glyphs are as follows:

1. *Pthumeru Ihyll* - jrwffkyp
2. *Great Isz* - rpzkeauc
3. *Lower Loran* - 6rxwxu3e

These [Blood Rocks](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Blood+Rock) can only be obtained *once per dungeon type* (Pthumeru, Loran, and Isz). That is, if you obtain a Blood Rock from *Pthumeru Iyhll* above, **no other Pthumeru chalice will yield a Blood Rock in a chest**. It will instead be replaced with [Great One's Wisdom](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Great+One's+Wisdom).

This means you can only get **three** Blood Rocks within the chalice dungeons, but this **excludes drops from bosses**. The last boss of any depth 5 chalice has a **small chance** of dropping a Blood Rock, but the only limiting factor here is *luck*; you can farm these bosses for Blood Rocks until your heart's content (or your patience runs out)!

Comment: Cannot find that Lower Loran chalice. Is the glyph correct?

Comment: @oedalis Apologies! The glyph for Lower Loran had a typo and it is now corrected. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Found the correct glyph: 6rxwxu3e