# Is there a way to go quickly to Mergo's loft?

Tags: bloodborne

I finished Bloodborne some times ago, so I respawned in NG+. Now I'm planning to do the DLC (so I have to go beat Amelia, etc.).

The thing is, in my previous game, I didn't take the blood rock. Shame on me. So I'm guessing : is there a way to go quickly to Mergo's loft and take it?

Or what are my options now? How can I have one "easily" (as easy as Bloodborne can be)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any "easy" way to get back to Mergo's loft, but you can get blood rocks elsewhere. The DLC has one (per playthrough), each family of chalice dungeon has one ([as detailed in this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243594/are-there-non-root-chalices-i-can-get-blood-rocks-from)), and an unlimited amount can be bought from the insight bath (requires 60 insight each).

Comment: I did the easy way : bought 2 blood rocks from the insight bath. Thanks!