# Which root chalice dungeons?

Tags: bloodborne

I can create Pthumeru, Loran, Isz, and Pthumeru Ihyll [root chalice dungeon](http://www.bloodborne-wiki.com/p/chalice-dungeons.html) as long as I finished the story mode dungeons. I understand that root dungeons will be randomly generated. I cannot use any [pre generated glyth](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k4GzUMm4-PdLK_mzkMpEdb7cOf5_mdV15tR9G0w2mbA/htmlview?usp=sharing&sle=true) as I am not playing online -- I do not have a PSN+ account. I understand that each root dungeon can also contain powerful loot on top of normal loot.

However, I am unclear as to whether or not the type (Pthumeru, Loran, Isz, or Pthumeru Ihyll) influences the kind of loot I can get?

Spending several hours doing a dungeons to find out that I only get a lost weapon or blood gem I have no intension to use kinda feels pointless.

In addition, which type contains the most blood echoes farming potentials? The first story Pthumeru dungeon chalice barely gave me enough blood echoes to replace the blood vials and bullets I spend. The less said about bolt paper, the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Blood echoes**: The most difficult ones -  depth 5, Root, with all offerings - will give you most amount of blood echoes. To unlock them you need to complete non-root versions first.

**Weapons and runes**: unfortunately without using glyphs you cannot reliably farm these. You can use doc you referenced to check which type of dungeon has desired item as loot and generate dungeons of this type til you get lucky.

**Blood Gems**: for gems situation is a bit better - each type of dungeon drops mostly one type of gems. Radial gems could be farmed in Pthumeru dungeons, Waning - in Loran, Triangular - in Isz. Best gems are cursed (so you need at least Cursed offering) from Depth 5 dungeons.

**Upgrade materials** drop in all types of dungeons, but better chances to get Blood Rock are in Depth 5 Root dungeons. Offerings don't affect material drop.

See also my answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/315451/144891).

Comment: Root Pthumeru dungeons look like not worth bothering with according to the  [spread sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k4GzUMm4-PdLK_mzkMpEdb7cOf5_mdV15tR9G0w2mbA/htmlview?usp=sharing&sle=true_) or is this just sample bias?

Comment: @Sardathrion yes, it looks so. Another [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1syKnSKflHbFiGY4pXkfIeXoMa2Lp9X1aXyme2qaTen4/edit#gid=1814333532) doesn't have much listed for this type. However, it can spawn Bath Messenger Shop, where you can purchase all custom versions of DLC weapons. But I'm sure I've seen this shop in other dungeon types as well.

Comment: Thanks. It kinda makes sense that the first root chalice you find is the weakest…