# Is there any reason to keep chalice dungeons after you've cleared them?

Tags: bloodborne

I've started doing some chalice dungeons in Bloodborne and I'm a little uncertain as to what to do once I have cleared them. There doesn't seem to be much help on it in the game (like everything else) so I'm not sure what I should be doing when I've got to the third level and killed the boss (And explored all side areas).

I have the option to remove the chalice but it occurs to me there might be a reason why it doesn't just go once you have completed it. Is there a way to restart it? Is there a way to do anything else? Or once I've killed and looted everything do i just remove it and start a new one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You can save dungeons to have quick access to Bath Messengers's shop which can be used to purchase weapons. Not every dungeon has this shop however.
2. There are some relatively good gems that drop from respawnable enemies. You can keep the dungeon to farm those whenever you want. (I've covered farming in some of my previous answers - [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/315451/144891) and [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/318955/144891)). This is very helpful if you don't have PS+ subscription and cannot just open one of the best possible dungeons (i.e. with bosses that drop the best gems) via glyphs.
3. You can farm blood echoes there if you got good mob placing right next to your lamp.
4. You can also farm materials required for dungeon creation (Ritual Blood and all the other stuff) in dungeons of any depth. Thanks @Ben for this one.

Comment: Cool. Many thanks. This seems to answer my question though I'll not accept yet in case somebody else wants to come along and answer too. :)

Comment: The only reason to keep lower level dungeons is farming for the items needed for higher level rituals

Comment: @Ben thanks, that's a good point, I'll add it into answer

Comment: @Ben: How does that work? My experience is that the ritual materials seem to be in chests rather than on mobs or is that just my limited experience with chalice dungeons showing? I assume farming a dungeon would involve dying to make everything respawn again?

Comment: @Chris a few respawnable enemies will drop ritual materials. Labyrinth Sages are a good example of this as they drop Sage's Hair and Sage's Wrist. You could die, exit and re-enter, or use a Bold Hunter's Mark to reset the regular dungeon enemies.